# Using $R^2$ as a measure of prediction accuracy

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have a model (not linear) that I am using to predict an outcome at a later time. I have plotted the model-predicted outcome versus the true outcome at various times, and I have a question. What would be the best metric to use to judge prediction performance? Someone suggested $R^2$, but technically I am not regressing the true outcome on the predicted outcome via a linear model, so I don't see how $R^2$ makes sense here.

Theoretically, I just have a given model, say f(t), and a true value f*(t). Does it make sense to list $R^2$ when plotting f(t) versus f*(t)? Or am I better just using some mean-squared error measurement?

Comment: $R^2$ is not a good measure for prediction accuracy. You will need to do cross-validation. $R^2$ is a measure for fitting.

Comment: I don't disagree. Does ${R}^2$ even make sense here?

Comment: I don't think so. In fact, I'm not even sure you can get $R^2$ for nonlinear regression to start with. Thus, there is nothing to discuss because you can't get it.

Comment: http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression

Comment: I'd get MSE with cross-validation.

Comment: Maybe adding a regression line is overkill on such a plot? I just don't see how such plots offer anything like a useful measure of prediction accuracy....does this make sense? The model itself is not linear but the ideal relationship between prediction and truth should be...

Answer (score 1):

$R^2$ by itself is not a good measure for prediction accuracy. In fact, anything with only the training set should not be sufficient. You will need to do cross-validation, which is not mentioned in your question.

You have a fitted model, and you plot the prediction vs actual values. But you still have just a single model, so you should only have a single $R^2$ (or pseudo $R^2$). Thus, I don't understand how you can plot f(t) vs f*(t) while listing $R^2$. The most common and simplest measure is cross-validated MSE.

Comment: Well the suggestion was since I am plotting a scatter plot of prediction versus truth, they will have a linear relationship in the ideal case (identity line) so that's where the idea for a linear model and R^2 came from, but I agree it's a weird use of R^2 if it is valid at all.

Comment: Here's another way to put it. Say I had a black box which gave me a prediction and then I had the true value. Is regressing the true value on the prediction (or vice versa) meaningful? People seem to do this sometimes....

Comment: @user85727 nothing wrong with your plotting.

Comment: But there seems to be a conceptual issue when I think about R^2. For example: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230692926_How_to_Evaluate_Models_Observed_vs_Predicted_or_Predicted_vs_Observed

Comment: At least the authors in the paper I linked made it seem like R^2 is reasonable and useful

Comment: Note you asked for prediction power. The paper is about goodness of fit. @user85727

Comment: I asked about how well the predictions match the observations. Isn't that a measurement of prediction performance?

Comment: @user85727 how well they match is not prediction power but goodness of fit

Comment: So the only difference is goodness of fit is for the same data and prediction is for new data?

Comment: What am I not understanding? :)

Comment: @user85727 To me, prediction is about performance for data that you don't use for training. $R^2$ is a good measure for fitting in a linear model, but not necessarily for prediction.